# Android - How to play video from a link in Webview?

Tags: android, webview

I want to play video from link in my code.

Run app such as image

https://c0109712b82b50aca46ad98aaf358dbbcebc484e.googledrive.com/host/0B2j8iTcQWJncMGJyU1M0UXBYRTA/Untitled.png

Click play but it does not work :(

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://m.kenh14.vn/video/secrets-mv-mary-lambert-90692.htm");
}
```

Comment: what kind ov video is it? either HTML5 or flash? Android doesnot support flash

Comment: I tried above link which is redirecting to another url & not to video, check your url again

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable javascript

```
WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```